# Quick HTML Table Sorting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, sorting, html-table

Yes, I know there are a **lot** of JS/jQuery programs out there to do this. I'm currently using http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/sorttable.js . It's very easy: just a JS file, add a few class attributes to your table, and you're off. In particular, you don't actually need to know JS to use it, and you can add custom sort keys without needing to write your own JS to extend it. I like it a lot for those two reasons. The main problem: my table is ~9300 rows long, and sorting takes 10-20 seconds. So I'm wondering, are any other scripts out there faster than this? These are the ones I've found:

http://webfx.eae.net/dhtml/sortabletable/sortabletable.html (Not even sure what this uses)
http://tablesorter.com/docs/ (Really really nice, but not easy to extend, requires knowing JS/jQuery)
http://flexigrid.info/ (Overkill, I just need a table sorter, not a whole data manipulation program)
http://datatables.net/ (Overkill, requires Js/jQuery to extend)

I'm sure there's 5000 other programs that can do what I want, but I don't have the time to figure out and test them all to see if they're fast. Thus I'd like to know if someone out there on StackOverflow can point me to whichever library they know to be fast, so I only have to figure out how to use one program.

(Btw, I've seen Java sort hundreds of thousands of numbers in milliseconds with quicksort; does anyone know what algorithm JS.sort() uses?)

Comment: you tagged this with jquery but it sounds like you want to avoid taking that dependency... which way is it?

Comment: Sure, java can sort *numbers* quickly, but you're sorting the *DOM*.  DOM operations are slow. Your issue starts with 9300 rows in a HTML table. I'd sort it server side. But if you don't want to do that, perhaps storing the data in a JS object, sorting, and re-rendering the table every time would be quicker.

Comment: @Robert: Yes, I'd like to avoid it, but I'll take anything that's fast and learn JQuery if that's necessary.

Comment: @Christian: I do deliver the HTML sorted by one column, but the data is interesting sorted from many different columns. The JS I currently use reads the HTML, stores the entries in an array, and then uses JS's builtin sort() on the array.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have had great success with DataTables (another jQuery plugin) with similar row numbers to what you are talking about. The speed loss you are seeing with javascript over what you have seen in java is it is actually rendering a DOM, which is a lot more work. The beauty of DataTables is you have the ability to source the data from a javascript array (essentially json) - so the sorting is done on the array (similar speed to java), and then only the part of the table the user needs to see is generated in the DOM.

See these urls for examples:

http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html

or

http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html

I suggest using the latter. If its still not fast enough using a static json array, you will want to build a serverside script to take the load off javascript - great example with serverside code here:

http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

## Edit: Infinite Scrolling

As discussed in the comments, the problem isn't the sort, but rather converting the HTML table to JS and back. This may help out by only loading rendering parts of the returned sort as the user views it; the server also provides the JS the same information as the table in JSON form. These two techniques eliminate the HTML-JS conversion and rendering problems, and thus greatly increase speed.

HTML (this is all that has to be rendered initially before the JSON comes along - add as many th tags as you have columns):

```
<table id="table_id">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
            <th>etc</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#table_id').dataTable( {
        "bScrollInfinite": true,
        "bScrollCollapse": true,
        "sScrollY": "200px",
        "bProcessing": true,
        "sAjaxSource": 'array.txt'
    });
});
```

array.txt contains:

```
{ "aaData": [
    ["This will be in column 1","This in two","this in 3"],
    ["another row - column 1","another two","another 3"]
]}
```

Comment: So what you're saying is that sorting isn't the hard part, but rather turning the 9300 lines of HTML into an array is what's taking so long? That's what the first link's preamble also seems to say. In that case, wouldn't it be easier for me to just modify the simple JS I already use so that it doesn't do its own parsing?

Edit: That's what Christian Varga was saying as well, wasn't it?

Comment: The browser rendering the DOM of thousands of rows before you even get to execute any javascript is what is taking so long - then converting that to an array will further slow it down. If you provide the data in an array to begin with, sort, and then only ask the browser to render the rows you need, you should see a vast speed increase.

Comment: Yeah it's actually the browser's rendering that takes the longest, check this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wkndw/. On my machine the numbers are generated, sorted, and appended to the dom in under 300ms (according to the profiler), yet it takes quite a lot longer for it to actually be rendered - in the realm of seconds.

Comment: Now I'm confused. As it is now, no JS is currently executed unless the user clicks on a table header, but the page loads just fine (displaying all 9200 rows). Only when a user clicks on a header, activating the JS, does the page not respond while the JS does its thing.   
Edit: You mean that rendering what the JS sort produces is what takes the time? Loading the page (and all 9229 rows) takes < 3 seconds.

Comment: Then you are correct - it is inefficiency in building your array from the DOM, and perhaps also the sort function. I havnt looked at the guts of datatables to see how they are handling the sorting, but I have acheived dyamic sorting on a table of over 10,000 rows and it performs well on everything except older versions of IE. I would give it a try, all you have to do is convert your table into a JSON array and save it as a text file. Ideally use serverside to remove the strain on js all together though. If the user re-sorts, just call a serverside script to return the json in the new order

Comment: Well, CV's link demonstrated that JS's built in sort(), which is what I use now, only takes ~350 ms to sort a random numerical array of 20,000 entries, so then reading and rendering is definitely the problem.      

The other problem is that I have barely a clue about making an interactive web server -- I can hardly use HTML as it is. Currently my table is generated straight to HTML from a Python script that collects the data from external sources.  
I could easily also make the JSON text file, but even then rendering the sorted array is still a large problem.

Comment: The problem may be the method your chosen plugin is currently using to render the table after the sort has been performed. This method may work better for you: http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/scroll_y_infinite.html - that renders the data post sort bit by bit - Otherwise your only alternative is server side.

Comment: That's perfect! Now I just gotta figure out how to use DataTables :P Thanks so much! (How do I upvote comments...?)

Comment: Pretend I upvoted it. ;) That requires 15 reputation :P (PS I added a few sentences about what the actual problem is.)

Comment: You now have 15 reputation :)

Answer (score 2):

Apart from libraries, table sorting is quite easy to do it by yourself.

The time it takes to actually sort the rows is negligible in relation to the time the DOM needs to move items around.

The one thing that WILL give you the best performance, is to detach the rows, arrange them according to your needs and attach them again. You don't need raw JSON data, just detach the $tr's, grab the values you want to compare from td's, make an array of $tr's, sort this array according to the column you want and attach them back to your tbody.

For example, with this technique I am sorting 3000 rows of 15 columns in 1 second time, which is totally viable. With that performance, the only problem is how to fetch 3000 rows to the browser...

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is a bit old, but here's the ES6+ solution that worked pretty great for me.

```
/**
 * Sort table data based on a direction of asc or desc for a specific column
 * @param {number} n- column number calling this sort
 * @param {string} dir -direction of the sort (asc or desc)
 * @param {HTMLSpanElement} targetElem -sort icon
 */
function sortTable(n, dir = "asc", targetElem) {
    targetElem.style.cursor = "progress";       
    let sortArr = [];
    let table =targetElem.closest('table');
    table.querySelectorAll('tbody > tr > td:nth-Child(' + parseInt(n) + ')').forEach((x, y) => sortArr.push(
        {
            sortText: x.innerHTML.toLowerCase(),
            rowElement: x.closest('tr')
        }));
    var sorted = sortArr.sort(function (a, b) {
        if (dir == "asc") {
            if (a.sortText < b.sortText) {
                return -1;
            }
        } else if (dir == "desc") {
            if (a.sortText > b.sortText) {
                return -1;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    });
    sorted.forEach((x, y) => {
        x.rowElement.parentNode.insertBefore(x.rowElement, x.rowElement.parentNode.children[y]);
    });
    targetElem.style.cursor = null;
}
```

In each of my th elements, I have sort icons that I use to call this function. They have their column numbers embedded in a data tag.
They look like:

```
<th data-field-name="lastLogin" role="columnheader" class="lastLogin">Last Login
    <span class="fa fa-unsorted sort-icon" title="Sort Descending" data-col-number="6" style="font-size: 1.2em; margin-left: 15px;"></span>
</th>
```

The click action for the icon:

```
click(icon){
        var parent = icon.closest('tr');
        parent.querySelectorAll('.sort-icon').forEach(x => {
            if (x == icon) {
                return;
            }
            delete x.dataset.dir;
            x.classList.replace('fa-sort-down', 'fa-unsorted');
            x.classList.replace('fa-sort-up', 'fa-unsorted');
        });

        if (icon.classList.contains('fa-unsorted')) {
            icon.classList.replace('fa-unsorted', 'fa-sort-up');
            icon.title = icon.title.replace('Ascending', 'Descending');
            icon.dataset.dir = "asc";
        } else if (icon.classList.contains('fa-sort-down')) {
            icon.classList.replace('fa-sort-down', 'fa-sort-up');
            icon.dataset.dir = "asc";
            icon.title = icon.title.replace('Ascending', 'Descending');
        } else if (icon.classList.contains('fa-sort-up')) {
            icon.classList.replace('fa-sort-up', 'fa-sort-down');
            icon.title = icon.title.replace('Descending', 'Ascending');
            icon.dataset.dir = "desc";
        }
        sortTable(icon.dataset.colNumber, icon.dataset.dir, icon);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this javascript library easy and powerful: 
http://tabulator.info

Tabulator allows you to create interactive tables in seconds from any HTML Table, JavaScript Array, AJAX data source or JSON formatted data.

Inside the cells you can put text, progress bar, images, other tables!