# Sorting a HTML table, which has inputs in it's <td>

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, extract, html-input

I was wondering if I can sort a table with JavaScript, which has input fields. I found a pretty nice plugin named **DataTables**, and it works flawlessly with basic tables, but not with table having inputs as it's fields.

Or would I be better off writing that kind of sorting/filtering with backend and passing just the data matching the request?

Comment: what´s the problem with inputs inside dataTables?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11304490/quick-html-table-sorting?rq=1

Comment: Assuming you're trying to sort the columns by the values in the `input` elements, then no plugin will do that by default. Datatables does let you write your own sorting logic though, so it's easy enough to add. If you need help with it, please add all relevant HTML/CSS/JS code to the question. With regard to your point about doing the sorting server or client side, that entirely depends on your use case and how much data is involved.

Comment: since you use DataTables this is what you looking for https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/dom_sort.html

Comment: @bobi this is absolutely that. Thank you very much. 
And everyone else too! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completeness, the solution given via comment was to use a plugin. Loosely cited from DataTables.net:

#### [Example: Live DOM ordering](https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/dom_sort.html)

... Use information available in the DOM to order columns.
Typically DataTables will read information to be ordered during its initialisation phase.
This will not be updated based on user interaction.
So ordering on columns with inputs may not reflect the current value of the inputs.

##### Getting current values

You must update the data that DataTables will order on, just prior to the order.
This method is much more efficient than actually ordering using the DOM, since only one DOM query is needed for each cell to be ordered.

#### [Docs: Sorting plug-ins – Custom data source sorting](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/#Custom-data-source-sorting)

Allows complete control of the data that is to be sorted. Typically this is used to retrieve data live from the DOM just prior to the table being sorted, to perform sorting on data that can be updated by the end-user or by some other script.

##### Predefined data extractors

- `<input type=text>` as string
- `<input type=text>` as numeric
- `<input type=select>` as string
- `<input type=checkbox>` as boolean